# vips/vips8 file not found #include <vips/vips8> in Ionic cordova in IOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I found an error in sharp.
After that, I found a blog in which they ask to delete sharp from the node module and run `sudo npm i`.

I have gone through GitHub and write `minipass - 2.7.0`

After that, I got a new error in

> vips/vips8 file not found #include <vips/vips8>

*I'm using Ionic with Angular on Macbook*

[image]

**I use commands which is**

```
1.sudo npm install
2.sudo npm i gulp-sass -ES --unsafe-perm=true
3.sudo ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: `brew install vips` works for me.

Comment: `brew install vips` worked for me too

Answer (score 24):

I very recently ran into a similar issue after making some changes to a project's package.json on my Mac (not an Angular or Cordova project).

I came across this GitHub issue for the `sharp` package which mentioned you may need to update the globally-installed version of `libvips`: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1148

In my case, since I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) but had not directly installed this package previously, I was able to resolve by running `brew install vips` and then re-running `npm install`. Note that it has a lot of dependencies so installation may take some time.

Edit: if that doesn't work, you may need to try a fresh install by removing `node_modules`, then re-running `npm i`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be not applicable to everyone, but remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory first and then try `npm install` again. (I also added the `minipass` in my `package.json`, by the way)

In my case, I had encountered the same error, but I could solve it by doing the above.