# sharp - "fatal error: 'vips/vips8' file not found" M2 (Apple Silicon) Macs

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, apple-silicon, sharp

I had this error: `fatal error: 'vips/vips8' file not found` while I was trying to setup a React project on my new M2(Apple Silicon) device.

In many issues reported on StackOverflow and github I figured out the problem was with the `vips`. You can find those issue reports below:

- [vips/vips8 file not found #include <vips/vips8> in Ionic cordova in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363572/vips-vips8-file-not-found-include-vips-vips8-in-ionic-cordova-in-ios)
- https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1882
- https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues/204

The main idea on those was `brew install vips` but this didn't solve my problem I was still getting the same error even though I checked if `vips` was installed without a problem using: `which vips`
I also tried `brew install --build-from-source gcc` but it didn't help too.

At last, I tried to run my entire Terminal in Rosetta following this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428768/on-apple-m1-with-rosetta-how-to-open-entire-terminal-iterm-in-x86-64-architec
but still it didn't work for me.

Versions:

- `yarn` version: 1.22.19
- `node` version: 16.15.1
- `npm` version: 8.11.0
- `sharp` version: 0.27.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using `npm` instead of `yarn`. For some reason when I tried to run `npm install` instead of `yarn install` everything worked out fine and now my app React app runs locally.

I don't know what is the reason behind this error. Most probably this issue will be fixed soon but if you are having this problem now, give it a try using `npm install` instead of `yarn install`.